# Typescript Enum with string values can only be compared as string

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have the following enum:

```
export enum SortDirection {
  Asc = "asc",
  Desc = "desc"
}
```

I've added the string values for my enum items so I can pass them into the lodash `orderBy` function.  This works well.

The problem, however, now occurs when I try to compare the enum as an enum.  Eg.

```
export function getSortColumnClass(column: any, currentColumn: any,
    currentDirection: SortDirection): string {
    let className = "sorted-header";
    if (currentDirection === SortDirection.Asc) {
        className += " sorted-header-asc";
    } 
    else {
        className += " sorted-header-desc";
    }
    return className;
}
```

Even though `currentDirection` is of type `SortDirection` in the function parameter list, `currentDirection === SortDirection.Asc` throws an error because `currentDirection` is coming through as a string.  When I check `typeof currentDirection`, it even returns `string`.  I would have to change the conditional to `currentDirection === 'asc'` which, of course, no longer makes it type-safe.

I'm expecting to be able to use the type-safe Enum item unless I were to call `toString()` on it to get the string "version" of the Enum value.

Comment: Why is `===` comparison not type-safe?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Having to use a string removes the type-safety that the enum affords..

Comment: Tried this in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) and there're no errors

Comment: @AlekseyL. Correct.  It doesn't actually throw an exception I suppose.  It just doesn't compare the expression successfully.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what's the problem

Comment: @AlekseyL. I want to compare my enum values as enum values, not as strings.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Even using `currentDirection as SortDirection` returns "unavailable" in my browser...

Comment: @im1dermike retracted.

Comment: I think I'm also failing to understand the question here.  You're expecting the items of a string enum to not be strings?  You are comparing "enum values as enum values" because the values of a string enum are strings.

Comment: I [tried this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Dir%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Asc%20%3D%20%22asc%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20Desc%20%3D%20%22desc%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getClass(dir%3A%20Dir)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(dir%20%3D%3D%3D%20Dir.Asc)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22sorted-header-asc%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22sorted-header-desc%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getClass(Dir.Asc)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getClass(Dir.Desc)%0D%0A)) and its working just fine.